# Can write this function using ##?

Tags: function-construction

```
scl[lo_List] := Module[{ll, tl, i},
        ll = Length[lo];
        tl = 0;
        For[i = 1, i <= ll, i++, tl = tl + lo[[i]]^2];
        tl]
```

something like

```
scl:=Plus[##^2] &
```

I admire those definitions that arrive to solutions with shorter coding

Comment: Is there a question here?

Comment: `scl[lo_List] := Total[lo^2]`?

Comment: isn't `scl = Dot`?

Comment: You've seen `Norm[]`, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
scl = Apply[Plus, ##^2] &;

lo = {1, 2, 3};

scl@lo
```

> 14

or

```
scl = Plus @@ (##^2) &;
```

and

```
scl = Plus @@ (#^2) &;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
♯♯ = +## & @@ (#^2) &;
♯♯ @ {1, 2, 3}
```

> 14

Comment: Hilarious :) well done.

Answer (score 0):

```
{1, 2, 3}^2 // Total
```

> 14

```
f = Total[#^2] &;

f@{1, 2, 3}
```

> 14